# Making a variable that includes other variables

Tags: python

I am new to coding and am struggling to make a variable that contains a lot of code. This is what I have been trying to do:

```
outputMSG = \nOvertime Hours:",format(OThours,',.2f'),'@ $' +format(OTrate, ',.2f'),'= $'\
                  +format(OTtotal,',.2f'),
            "\nRegular Hours:",format(regHours,',.2f'),'@ $' +format(rate,',.2f'),'= $'\
                  +format(regTotal,',.2f')
```

Whenever I print this, it does not format correctly and just shows all of the code above. I think my issue is using commas wrong because when tested on a smaller scale that was the issue, but I dont know how to fix it. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You have to use `+` to concatenate strings, not `,`. `,` is for making tuples.

Comment: You're also missing the `"` before `\nOvertime`

Answer (score 1):

The original code was missing some quotation marks. And it was not runnable code because of missing variables.

The following code is runnable with variables assigned constant values.

I hope this provides insight on providing Minimal Runnable Example for future questions.

```
OThours = 20
OTrate = 11.11
OTtotal = OThours * OTrate
regHours = 35
rate = 5.50
regTotal = regHours * rate

outputMSG = "Overtime Hours:" + format(OThours,',.2f') + '@ $' + format(OTrate, ',.2f') + '= $'\
                  + format(OTtotal,',.2f')\
            + "Regular Hours:" + format(regHours,',.2f') + '@ $' +format(rate,',.2f') + '= $'\
                  + format(regTotal,',.2f')

print(outputMSG)
```

Output:

```
Overtime Hours:20.00@ $11.11= $222.20Regular Hours:35.00@ $5.50= $192.50
```

Comment: I had the other variables above in my code, but using the plus sign instead of commas worked, thank you!

Comment: @charleywm, Using the plus sign is fine. The answer I provided uses the plus sign. If any answer provides the response you needed. Please accept it. It does not have to be my answer. By the way, if you are learning on your own, research the f-string for formatting. If you are part of a class maybe wait for the instructor to introduce f-string.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed equation:

```
outputMSG = "Overtime Hours:" + format(OThours,',.2f') + '@ $' + format(OTrate, ',.2f') + '= $'\
                  + format(OTtotal,',.2f')\
            + "Regular Hours:" + format(regHours,',.2f') + '@ $' +format(rate,',.2f') + '= $'\
                  + format(regTotal,',.2f')
```

**KISS**

keep it simple silly

Sometimes, code like this is hard to read, causing some syntax errors. Next time, try using more variables instead of directly embedding equations, or using classes.

**Good Luck!**